# How do I paste text with Android clipboard manager in an empty input in a WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

We have a web page with an input element on a webview App on Android.

If the input text is not empty, has text, you can touch and the clipboard manager is launched and shows:

- When clipboard is empty "select all"
- When clipboard is full "paste, select all"

BUT, when the input text is empty you can not launch the clipboard manager in order to paste text.

Should I implement onLongClick on Android webview app? if yes, what is the code to simply launch the Android Clipboard Manager?

Should I add an html paste button and solve it with html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best solution I have found, just get the text of the clipboard and paste it throug javascript when longclick is done in a focused input of a web page loaded in myWebView

```
myWebView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip;
                clip = clipboard.getPrimaryClip();
                String str = clip.getItemAt(0).getText().toString();
                myWebView.evaluateJavascript("try{document.activeElement.value='"+str+"';}catch(e){}", new ValueCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {}
                });
                return true;
            }
        });
```